# Необходимо найти все дополнительные диагонали(паралельные основной диагонали) - Python

Tags: python, алгоритм, список

Такое задание найти все дополнительные диагонали(паралельные основной диагонали)
Начал решать так,такое решение дает только одну дополнительную диагональ и все,мне нужно
чтобы давало остальные.

```
def checkio(matrix):
    results=[]
    x=0
    for k,row in enumerate(matrix):
        for i,elm in enumerate(row):
            if(x+1==i):
                results.append(elm)
                x=i
                break
        results.append('---')     
    print(results) 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    checkio([[11, 2,  4,   7],
            [ 4,  5,   6,  0],
            [10, 8, -12, -1],
            [10, 8, -12, -1]])#<---[2, '---', 6, '---', -1, '---', '---']
```

Comment: Вложенный цикл здесь не нужен: i всегда в результате его выполнения становится равно x + 1, x увеличивается на единицу, elm становится равным row[i]. И таким образом Вы пробегаете лишь по правому верхнему углу матрицы, забывая о левом нижнем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если говорить лишь о квадратных матрицах, то можно chekio модифицировать так:

```
def checkio(matrix):
    results = []
    for counter in range(1, len(matrix)):
        diag_length = len(matrix) - counter
        results.extend([
            [matrix[i][i + counter] for i in range(diag_length)], # top-right
            [matrix[i + counter][i] for i in range(diag_length)]  # bottom-left
        ])

    print(results)
```

`counter` здесь имеет смысл расстояния от главной диагонали до параллельной диагонали (а параллельных на заданном расстоянии две: в углах справа-сверху (top-right) и слева-снизу (bottom-left) от главной диагонали). Расстояние между соседними диагоналями понимается равным единице. Стартуем с единицы чтоб не учитывать саму главную диагональ.

```
# [[2, 6, -1], [4, 8, -12], [4, 0], [10, 8], [7], [10]]
```

Comment: Смысл чёрточек ('---'), как я понял, косметический, поэтому в ответе их нет

Comment: И `results` у меня список искомых диагоналей

Comment: Кстати, возможно, верхнюю границу в `range(1, len(matrix)):` для `counter` нужно уменьшить на единицу, потому что вопрос о том, параллельна ли диагональ, содержащая единственный элемент, чему-либо, вполне резонный.

Comment: Здорово)вы очень тщательно объяснили)